# Replace "-" with ":" for vendor MAC Address

Tags: linux, shell, sed

I want to replace the "-" with ":" for a list of vendor MAC Addresses.

for example:

```
F4-CE-46   Hwltt-Packard Company
```

to

```
F4:CE:46   Hwltt-Packard Company
```

Does it possible?

Sorry for my bad english...

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about Linux and belongs on [unix.se].

Comment: I believe it to be on topic, because OP wants command line code. Code is code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$ echo F4-CE-46 | tr - :
F4:CE:46
```

Or for one field:

```
$ echo F4-CE-46 Abc-Def | awk '{ gsub("-", ":", $1) ; print }'
F4:CE:46 Abc-Def
```

Comment: I need only replace MAC, not all text... :/

Comment: You can remove the `print` `awk '{gsub("-", ":", $1)}1'`

Answer (score 0):

If your input is always going to be in the same format as what you provided, `awk` can do this quite easily:

```
AirBoxOmega:Downloads d$ echo "F4-CE-46   Hwltt-Packard Company" |awk '{gsub("-",":",$1);print}'
F4:CE:46 Hwltt-Packard Company
AirBoxOmega:Downloads d$
```

[Here](http://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/String-Functions.html) is a link to some details about the `awk`'s `sub()` function, but put simply it takes three arguments:

```
awk '{sub("-",":",$1);print}'
          ^Text to replace  #First arg
               ^what to replace with  #second arg
                   ^which field to do replacements in (defaults to all if not specified) #third (optional) arg
```

This should let you change the characters in the first column, or $1 in awk (remember awk is *not* zero indexed) but not affect the other column. Hope this helps.